# asp.net 3.5 url rewriting / routing for multilingual websites

Tags: url-rewriting, asp.net-3.5, url-routing

I'd like to implement the asp.net 3.5 url routing functionality to take in links like www.mysite.com/fr/blah/page1.aspx
www.mysite.com/en/blah/page1.aspx
and redirect them to the same page.  I've read through and tried the approach in the following tutorial: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131035/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051309-1.aspx.  However this tutorial doesn't address the issue of generically mapping urls like I want to.  For example,
they have rules like

routes.Add(
      "All Categories",
         new Route("Categories/All", new CategoryRouteHandler())
      );
in the global.asax, and then they create a specific CategoryRouteHandler that handles the above url.  I want a generic handler that will handle all the urls.  In short I want to be able to handle a rule like the following:

routes.Add(
      "All Languages",
         new Route("/{language}/*", new LanguageRouteHandler())
      );

The problem with this is, that in the LanguageRouteHandler, I'd have to instantiate and return a page object!  However, I don't know which page to return.  How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I accomplished this:

routes.Add("Lang", new Route("{lang}/{*page}", new LangRouteHandler()));

this handles my situation.